# Java and Selenium: Getting list contents when id's and selectors are poorly written

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I've got a, IMO, poorly written piece of markup with a  which cannot be altered. I'm trying to get the text and specific selectors from the li elements, but I'm having trouble.

```
<hb-felt-radio id="residenceChoice" data-e2e-selector="residence-choice">
 <hb-felt>
  <div translate="">
   <fieldset>
    <div>
     <span translate="" id="residence-legend" data-e2e-selector="residence-question"> 
      How do you live today? 
     </span>
    </div>
    <ul class="hb-feltliste">
     <li>
      <input type="radio" id="residence-RENT_GOV" data-e2e-selector="residence-RENT_GOV">
       <div class="hb-label">
        <label class="hb-label-tekst" for="residence-RENT_GOV">
         Renting governmental
        </label>
       </div>
     </li>
     <li>
      <input type="radio" id="residence-RENT_PRIVATE" data-e2e-selector="residence-RENT_PRIVATE">
      <div class="hb-label">
       <label class="hb-label-tekst" for="residence-RENT_PRIVATE">Renting private</label>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </fieldset>
  </div>
 </hb-felt>
</hb-felt-radio>
```

I'm trying to get the label text and the for= from the label in each li, as well as the ID from the select. But, with my very limited understanding of XPath (since I usually can enforce better selectors), I don't see how I can get them?

I've tried things like

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("hb-felt-radio[data-e2e-selector='bosted-valg'] div/fieldset/ul/li")).stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("\"//hb-felt-radio[id='bosituasjonValg']//div//fieldset//ul//li")).stream().map(WebElement::getText).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But I haven't cracked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up xPath and CSS. Below is the example how you can use **CSS** for fetching what you need:

```java
List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(
        new ByChained(By.cssSelector("#residenceChoice"),
                      By.cssSelector(".hb-label-tekst")
        ));
labels.forEach(webElement -> {
    System.out.println("Label text: " + webElement.getText());
    System.out.println("Label 'for': " + webElement.getAttribute("for"));
});
```

And this is the exampel for **xPath**:

```java
List<WebElement> labels = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='residenceChoice']//label[@class='hb-label-tekst']"));
labels.forEach(webElement -> {
    System.out.println("Label text: " + webElement.getText());
    System.out.println("Label 'for': " + webElement.getAttribute("for"));
});
```

Comment: Great, thanks :-) I know I was mixing up a bit, since I was trying both methods. But apparently I didn't know how much I was mixing it up :-)

Comment: By the way: Do you see an elegant/easy way to select (click on) a label in the list based on the visible text? ("Renting private", for example)?

Comment: Not to much context to give you a good answer, but I would start from simply `//label[text()='Renting private']`. Like this: http://xpather.com/Utab0pmz